# Install nvidia proprietary drivers 17.10 on laptop

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 17.10, nvidia-prime

I've been trying for a week or so to get Ubuntu 17.10 to work with NVIDIA drivers. I've been on several forums, tried a lot of methods, but I can't figure it out.

What is the best method to install NVIDIA drivers on a laptop?
Can someone point me in the right direction?

I have a Clevo laptop with a GeForce GTX1060 6gb video card, and Intel integrated chip.

Comment: Have you tried downloading and installing from NVIDIA Webiste directly?
http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html

Comment: Even on this site it seems you can download Linux Drivers https://www.geforce.com/drivers

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't want to install. It says the nouveau driver should be removed first.

Comment: I have found out that if I change my uefi boot settings to boot only discrete graphics card, I can use the nvidia drivers.

Comment: @AbelTom I tried with the drivers from the NVIDIA website. Also results in black screen...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful link to install Nvidia drivers. I hope it helps:
http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux

It worked well for me. You can also check which driver you need for the card using

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Comment: I this but I still boot to a black screen.

Comment: Are you trying to run on Xorg? Nvidia is more or less not compatible with Xorg. Try using unity. It should work.

Comment: @sudhanvalalit - unity is a desktop running on X.org. nVidia drivers have issues with wayland.

Comment: @ravery Thanks for the info. i didn't know it when I posted the answer. Best way would be to comment wayland (as shown in other posts) and then do the steps mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the system search menu (click the super button), type 'additional drivers', then choose the proprietary driver option and let it install the driver automatically.